# Parameterized variable type in function (c++)

Tags: c++, function, variables, arguments, parameterized

I am trying to write something along the following lines:

```
void setData<T>(char * environmentVariable, T &data, T defaultValue)
{
    bool ret = false;
    // Try to get the environmentVariable
    ret = handle.getParam(environmentVariable, data);
    if(!ret)
    {
        data = defaultValue
    }
}

int main()
{
    int valOne;
    float valTwo;

    // Get a value of type int
    setData("some_int_value", valOne, 10);  // 10 is the default value

    // Get a value of type float
    setData("some_float_value", valTwo, 0.05f);  // 0.05 is the default value

}
```

One way to do this is to have a va_list. Is there a way I can accomplish this with a class?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? (aside from `0.05` instead of `0.05f`)

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What are you trying to do? Where does `va_list` come into this?

Comment: I get this compilation error:  >> error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token

Comment: I basically want to write a type agnostic function.

Comment: I have also tried calling the function as setData<float>(,,) or setData<int>(,,)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you were almost there:

```
template<typename T>
void setData(char * environmentVariable, T &data, T defaultValue)
{
    // ...
}
```

This should do what you want. Notice, however, that the same `T` is used for the last two arguments, so this function call would make it impossible to deduce `T`:

```
setData("some_float_value", valTwo, 0.05);
```

Because `0.05` is a `double`, while `valTwo` is a float. During type deduction, a similar conversion won't be performed, since the compiler is trying to match the *exact* types.

This is easy to fix though:

```
setData("some_float_value", valTwo, 0.05f); 
//                                      ^
```

The `f` suffix makes the last argument is a prvalue of type `float`, so that `T` can be deduced to be `float`.

---

Possibly, you may want to allow different types for the second and the third argument, as long as the third one can be converted to the second one. In this case, you could redefine your function template as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void setData(char * environmentVariable, T &data, U defaultValue)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, notice that this would give you the freedom to instantiate `setData()` with *any* two types `T` and `U`, while you probably want your template to be instantiated only for `U`s which are convertible to `T`s. Some SFINAE trick combined with the `std::is_convertible<>` type trait will do the job:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U,
         typename std::enable_if<
             std::is_convertible<U, T>::value
             >::type* = nullptr>
void setData(char * environmentVariable, T &data, U defaultValue)
{
    // ...
}
```

Now you can even use your original call without getting compiler errors:

```
setData("some_float_value", valTwo, 0.05); 
//                                  ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This was exactly what I was looking for. I had made a typo in the origin question; I did mean to have an f.

Comment: But besides the f issue, this syntax was what I was looking for. Thanks again.